# Implement Android GCM on Ruby on Rails 4 server using rpush gem?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an Android app and I need to implement a GCM service for it. The server works on **Ruby on Rails 4** and it uses the gem **rpush** (I can't change the gem because this was already used by someone else to implement the equivalent service for iOS). I really have no idea on how to start on this, becasue I'm pretty new developing in Android.

Is there any tutorial out there that you could recommend? or what are the steps to implement this service in my server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I finally decided to stop using **rpush** pretty much because the docs sucks. I am now using [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) to send push notifications. It works pretty well so that's my recommendation.

Hope it works for you guys!

Comment: I think because of recent events (parse going down) I think RPush can be better solution as one gem that supports both Android and iOS. Alternatively you can use just GCM gem which is wrapper around Google CLoud Messaging API.

Comment: Yes, @BartoszŁęcki this happened before I realized Parse was going down. We are now using Firebase and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Rpush provides API for [sending push messages via GCM](https://github.com/rpush/rpush#google-cloud-messaging). Additionally you can get inspired by the existing code for APNS (iOS pushes).

Answer (score 1):

You can check this blog post that contains a minimal working example of an Android App with Rails server:
http://mateuyabar.com/blog/android/rubyonrails/gcm/2015/05/13/Google-Cloud_Messaging-with-Ruby-On-Rails.html

Or check its source at:
https://github.com/mateuyabar/blog_gcm_and_ror